# Django type object 'Template' has no attribute 'objects'?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

i am using Django 1.10.5. this error comes when i click on 
AttributeError at /rentacar/list/

**Views**

**imports**

```
from rentacar.forms import *
from template.models import Template
from module.models import *

@csrf_protect
def rentacar_list(request, page_number=1):
    menu_config_list = MenuItemRentacarList.objects.all()[0]
    menu_config = MenuItemRentacarList.objects.get(id=menu_config_list.id)

    all_cars = Car.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    if menu_config.menu_item_rentacar_list_show_unavailable == 0:
        all_cars = all_cars.exclude(car_available=0)
    else:
        all_cars = all_cars

    cars_page = Paginator(all_cars, menu_config.menu_item_rentacar_list_pagination)
    args['cars'] = cars_page.page(page_number)
    template = Template.objects.get(template_default__exact=1)
    args['main_menu'] = MenuMenu.objects.get(id__exact=template.template_main_menu_id)
    args['menu_items'] = MenuItem.objects.filter(
        menu_item_menu=args['main_menu'],
        menu_item_published=1,
    )
    template_page = template.template_alias + str("/rentacar/rentacar_cars_list.html")
    args['current_menu_item'] = menu_config.menu_item_rentacar_list_menu_item
    all_modules = Module.objects.filter(
        module_show_option__exact='all',
        module_published=1
    )
    selected_modules = Module.objects.filter(
        module_show_option__exact='selected',
        module_published=1,
        module_menu_item=args['current_menu_item']
    )
    excluded_modules = Module.objects.filter(
        module_show_option__exact='except',
        module_published=1,
    ).exclude(
        module_menu_item=args['current_menu_item']
    )
    args['modules'] = list(chain(all_modules, selected_modules, excluded_modules))
    return render(request, template_page, args)
```

**Urls**

```
url(r'^rentacar/list/$', extension_views.rentacar_list),
```

i am using template as a model and defining the template object and getting it from my template app.is there any easy way to render my template.

**Exception Location**: D:\buggy\extension\views.py in rentacar_list, line 766

**Template Model**

```
from mega_admin.models import MenuMenu



class Template(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = "template"
        verbose_name = "Template"
        verbose_name_plural = "Templates"

    template_title = models.CharField(
        verbose_name="Template title",
        max_length=200
    )
    template_alias = models.CharField(
        verbose_name="Template alias",
        max_length=200
    )
    template_description = models.TextField(
        verbose_name="Template description",
        blank=True,
    )
    template_version = models.IntegerField(
        verbose_name="Template version",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    template_default = models.BooleanField(
        default=0,
        blank=False,
        null=False
    )
    template_main_menu = models.ForeignKey(
        MenuMenu,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.template_title + str(" v") + str(self.template_version)

class TemplatePosition(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = "template_position"
        verbose_name = "Template position"
        verbose_name_plural = "Template positions"

    template_position_template = models.ForeignKey(
        'template.Template',
        related_name="template_position_template_key",
        verbose_name="Template positions template",
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    template_position_name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name="Template position name",
        max_length=200,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
    template_position_alias = models.CharField(
        verbose_name="Template position alias",
        max_length=200,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )

    # def __unicode__(self):
    #   return u'%s' % self.template_position_name
```

**Traceback**

```
File "D:\projects\buggy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "D:\projects\buggy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "D:\projects\buggy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "D:\projects\buggy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "D:\buggy\extension\views.py" in rentacar_list
  766.     template = Template.objects.get(template_default__exact=1)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /rentacar/list/
Exception Value: type object 'Template' has no attribute 'objects'
```

Comment: Please show the definition for Template, and also how you're importing it in that view.

Comment: do i show th template model ? or do i show the html file of this template ?

Comment: The Template model, and the import statement in this view.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Please Check i had updated.

Comment: post the whole traceback

Comment: What's in `module.models`? Does it define or import anything called Template?

Comment: @DanielRoseman in module model there is no Template or any thing i had imported.

Comment: @DanielRoseman is there any other way. if i not use Template app and make template file like html and give path and render to html page.?

Comment: Is it possible that `Template` is confused with the Django [Template object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/templates/#template)?

Comment: @Cyrlop i was using django cms book and learning from there . i know the easy way to use as a template file but i tried to do as cms book doing first it was working after that i had added some send mail function in my views and using a driver id i dont know where this error comes .

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sir what should i do . any solution please

Comment: Just before that line in views.py can you put `print(Template)` and post what it shows in the console?

Comment: <class 'django.template.base.Template'>
<QueryDict: {}>
Internal Server Error: /rentacar/car/5/driver/1/

Comment: @DanielRoseman this error comes on all the pages where i am using   template = Template.objects.get(template_default__exact=1)
AttributeError: type object 'Template' has no attribute 'objects'

Comment: Right so that's telling you that somehow you have imported the built-in Django template class, not your Template model. But the code you have posted doesn't show where you're doing that so it's impossible to help.

Comment: yeah i am using builtin django template class also . both of them . in other views

Comment: but i dont know how to do this . what sould i do . do i convert this Template and use djago built in temps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this Error is Coming due to i am importing my custome model template and built  in Template

```
from template.models import Template
from django.template import Context, Template
def func1(request):

  template = **Template**.objects.get(template_default__exact=1)

def func2(request):            
      template = **Template** ("""link{{ request.get_host }}{% url 'detail' driver_id=driver_id %}""")
```

Same Template name  with different import.One is built-in import and second is model import thats why attribute error is occuring.

Special Thanks to :

**Willem Van Onsem**

*Alasdair*

*Daniel Roseman*

this answer resolve by these great men.